# What is Putin's stance on United States invading Syria and overthrowing the Assad regime?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, syria, civil-war

Rex Tillerson said that [steps are underway to remove the Assad regime](https://www.yahoo.com/news/tillerson-steps-way-remove-assad-power-syria-200018022.html#mycomments). The United States has also accused Assad of using chemical weapons, yet provided no clear evidence or documentations other than reports by people in the area.

This is striking similar to the invasion of Iraq based on false accusations of Weapons of Mass Destruction being used by Saddam Hussein. What's Putin's stance on US invasion of Syria? He said he is in support of the Assad regime (ally to Russia) but now with talks of chemical weapons, what's his stance?

Comment: I'm afraid, other than the use of the word "WMD," the "striking" similarity.  You had a lot of innuendo and no evidence of anything in the run-up to Iraq.  You have a documented gas attack where the munitions were dropped from planes - capabilities that the rebels don't have.  Plus Assad's proven and acknowledge chemical and nerve agent program, where he surrender stockpiles of weapons, but did not show any verifiable move to dismantle the production capabilities.  The similarities are superficial, and really only seem striking if you're unfamiliar with the details of both situations.

Answer (score 11):

Obviously Putin is against the overthrow of Assad, even with the recent chemical weapons attack. The Russian government has already stated that it does not believe it was the Syrian government who was responsible for the gas attack and has clearly signaled that it would veto any UN security resolution.

Now as you mentioned yourself, that does not block the US from taking its own actions. Logically Putin would be against US action as well for the same reasons. But at this point the US is acting as its own sovereign state — Putin can't tell it what to do.

The next question is: what is Putin willing to do to prevent unilateral by the US? To this, the answer is unknown. Would he threaten military intervention? Personally I don't believe so, but it's impossible to say. [Russia does already have ground forces in Syria](https://www.wsj.com/articles/russian-special-forces-seen-as-key-to-aleppo-victory-1481884200), as well as air, so who knows.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*Would he threaten military intervention?*". Russian army (especially the Air Force) are already very active on the Syrian theater, if spite of twice announcing a pull out.

Comment: "even with the recent chemical weapons attack" - you meant alleged CW attack. As you could have figured out by now, this was another US/western lie. See Robert Fisk's articles, if everything which does not speak english is "fake news" for you.